# How to make Numeric Entries in Xamarin Forms wait until user is done entering number

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a NumericEntry in Xamarin Forms, that for example wants to check if a number is equal to 50, but when the user starts to enter 50, they enter the "5" first, but then immediately it's wrong, because 5 != 50 obviously. How do I make it so that the user can enter the full number, but then once they click away from the entry/press enter on the keyboard, then we check if the number is equal to 50?

Specifically what I'm looking for that would make things a lot easier is a keyword that says the entry isn't "highlighted" anymore, meaning the user clicked enter on the keyboard, or tapped away from the entry on the screen somewhere. Is there something like that that exists?

Right now the code that I'm working on has two functions, an UpdateText and a OnTextChanged, and every time the text changes (the 5 gets entered in my example), then UpdateText immediately gets called, but I want to make a condition that checks if the user is done before UpdateText gets called.

Thanks!

edit: I found something called "IsFocused", would this be the right way to use it?

```
IsFocused="{Binding EntrySelected}"
```

would be in my XAML file, and in my C# file, `public bool UserFinished;

```
    public bool EntrySelected
    {
        get
        {
            return UserFinished;
        }
        set
        {
            UserFinished = value;
        }
    }
```

and using  `if(EntrySelected){` inside my functions?

Comment: do you mean an Entry with Keyboard=Numeric?  Or are you using some 3rd party control?

Comment: @Jason it's an Entry with Keyboard=Numeric

Comment: I suppose if it is a problem with it firing per click, one solution (albeit extreme), is to make a custom render of an empty Entry; this way it won't have that issue

Answer (score 0):

use the [Completed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.entry.completed?view=xamarin-forms) event.  You can also customize the appearance of the [Return](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/entry#customizing-the-return-key) key using the `ReturnType` property

```
<Entry Completed="Entry_Completed" ReturnType="Send" />


void Entry_Completed (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var text = ((Entry)sender).Text; //cast sender to access the properties of the Entry
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so I'm a little confused on how this works, when the user clicks return, will the Entry_Completed function automatically be called?

Comment: from the docs I linked to: "Occurs when the user finalizes the text in an entry with the return key."

Comment: Ok thanks! So my plan right now is to actually just update a global boolean "UserFinished" to true (inside the EntryCompleted function), and then in my UpdateText function add a condition that UserFinished = true before I check the number. 

Now what if the user clicks return, but then goes to edit the text again, is there a way to make UserFinished false again? When they tap on the entry for a second time?

Comment: I'm also getting an error from my XAML page, saying that the EventHandler "EntryCompleted" with correct signature not found

Comment: use the Focus event to detect when they re-enter the field.  Do you have an EntryCompleted handler in your code-behind?

Comment: Yes, it's 

        `public bool UserFinished = false;


        void EntryCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {

            UserFinished = true;

        }`

Comment: try adding `protected` access modifier

Comment: Oh I think I figured out the problem, I was putting the EntryCompleted function in my Behaviours file instead of the samename.xaml.cs file. However, if I put it in the .xaml.cs file, it says the local function is not used and gives me an error. Where am I supposed to put the EntryCompleted function?

Comment: in the code behind of the xaml file where you are using it.  This is a basic C# concept

Comment: But if I put the UserFinished boolean and EntryCompleted function that changes it in that C# file, how are the functions located in my Behaviours file supposed to access it? Is this just not possible?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with Behaviors.  You asked about how to detect when the user completed an Entry.  If you now need help with a new problem, ask a new question.